# How to add custom buttons in vis js?

Tags: javascript, vis.js, visnetwork

Vis js offers buttons for navigations. I want to have my own buttons like them which stay at their location even when the whole network moves around. I tried drawing on the canvas but the drawings move when the network moves. I also tried creating a new button with the `class= vis-button vis-myButton` and adding custom css for myButton but that also didn't work.

Navigation Button example: https://visjs.github.io/vis-network/examples/network/other/navigation.html

How do I do it? Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You will have to create the button outside the network UI because vis js creates a canvas for its UI and we cannot add our custom elements in it.

If added then it will react to the movement and styling of the network UI.

For example, I have created a network UI in react js so I have two components, one for network UI and another for buttons which I can put anywhere on the screen.

Pseudo Code:

```
<parent div>
<button compnent/>
<network component />
</div>
```

you can set parent div as position: relative and button to position: absolute and adjust the position, so it won't go outside the main div.